# Why does my Xcode bot trigger twice?

Tags: xcode, continuous-integration, xcode-server

I've been working on using Xcode server to build my app, and have been running into some snags. The most recent involves Bots running over-zealously. I'll commit and push one change to one file, and two builds get triggered, separated by a minute or two. This also happens if I click the "Integrate Now" button, or if I make changes to the bot, *with "Integrate immediately" unchecked*.

Since my build takes a while to run, this is a pretty big problem, especially when I'm trying to iterate on Bot configuration.

Is anyone aware of what process triggers builds, or how can I troubleshoot this type of failure in general? It seems like there are multiple daemons listening for the signal to trigger the build or something like that.

Since it may be a bug in the Xcode beta, I submitted a radar (rdar://20456212)

Comment: I'm also running into this. Filed a radar as well (20530374)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem.  I changed the bot so that it does not do a clean for each integration and now it only does one build per commit.  My guess is that the clean process and download of code was taking so long that the bot was being triggered before it was complete.  So now I clean once a day and I only get a double build on the first build of the day.  Hope this helps.

Comment: I agree, it's definitely triggered by a clean build. Have you tried with Xcode 7 + El Cap? I haven't yet.

Comment: This looks to be fixed with the combination of Xcode 7 and Server 5 (I upgraded both simultaneously, so it's possible only one was necessary).